# Why the need of two classes in one file when using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm currently trying to learn (struggling) MVVM and I came across [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/mvvm_first_application.htm) tutorial where two classes are used within the same file and it got me wondering if this has to do with MVVM or not.

1. Why the use of two classes if class `StudenModel` is never used?
2. Does that has to do with MVVM?
3. Can someone explain why would you ever put two classes in one file?

Thanks

Comment: There is no reason. No, there is no need for unused classes in MVVM. Just remove it.

Comment: "I read a tutorial and am confused by it" that means it's a lousy tutorial.  Ditch it and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Why the use of two classes if class `StudentModel` is never used?

   There is none. Probably a bug in the tutorial. `Student` seems to be the model already. Also, multiple classes can reside in one file, and one class can be spanned over multiple files. It doesn't really matter to the compiler.
2. Does that has to do with MVVM?

   No.
3. Can someone explain why would you ever put two classes in one file?

   It is a matter of taste. I don't like it actually, but sometimes it is not very useful to create a new file for a two line class. Then it is better sometimes to group related classes together.

   (Sample of such a two line class. Not to be meant as a good example to use, just a how:)

   ```
   public class SpecialEventArgs : EventArgs<SomeClass>
   { }
   ```